# How to use IF/SEARCH to check if a cell contains a substring, and return one of five strings to effectively "label" the cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a column in my Google Sheet that contains the title of each of our e-blasts from the past 7 years. I want to create a column that provides the "type" of the e-blast, using IF/SEARCH or something similar to find a substring in the first column and return a string in the last column.

*We didn't necessarily label each event invitation with the word "invitation," for example — e.g., there were some invitations labeled as "reminder." :(*

Basically, I want to search for a set of words like "reminder" and "invitation" and have the cell return the string "Event Invite." But here's where I'm running into trouble:
In the same stroke, I need to also search the cell for the substring "e-blast" and have it return "Newsletter," and "follow up" should return "Recap," and so on.

**Thanks so so much in advance for any advice!!**

PS: Here's what I'm trying, but it returned an error.

```
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(IFS(SEARCH(”Reminder| Date| Webinar| Conference| Invitation| Invite| Fireside| Session| Fair| Panel”,C4:C)=true,”Event”, 
                        SEARCH(”Newsletter| Blast”,C4:C)=true,”Newsletter”
                        SEARCH(”Apply| Applications”,C4:C)=true,”Call for Applications”
                        SEARCH(”Recap| Recording| Follow”,C4:C)=true,”Recap”)))
```

[image: Google Sheets screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html). To learn the exact regular expression syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Here is a simple example.

```
=arrayformula( 
  ifs( 
    regexmatch(C4:C, "(?i)Newsletter|Blast"), "Newsletter", 
    regexmatch(C4:C, "(?i)Apply|Application"), "Call for Applications", 
    regexmatch(C4:C, "(?i)Recap|Recording|Follow"), "Recap", 
    regexmatch(C4:C, "(?i)Reminder|Date|Webinar|Conference|Invitation|Invite|Fireside|Session|Fair|Panel"), "Event", 
    true, iferror(1/0) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: @May - note that  `(?i)` modifier is used there for `case-insensitive` matching

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).

Comment: @doubleunary Got it! Thanks.